# Git for Windowsのincludeセクションでpathを~を使って設定するとファイルを読み込まない

Tags: windows, git

WindowsのGitを使っています。
WindowsとWSLでgitの設定の共通化をするためにincludeを使おうとしたのですが、ホームディレクトリを示すはずの"~"が使えません。

最小限の構成として、~/temp下に

`.gitconfig`

```
[include]
  path = "~/temp/config2"
```

`config2`

```
[user]
  name = "Git Tester"
```

の2つのファイルを作成しました、

さらに、コマンドラインで以下のコマンドを実行しました。

```
C: /temp > git init

C: /temp > git config include.path ~/temp/config2

C: /temp > git config --list
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
include.path=~/temp/config2

C: /temp >
```

結果は上記の通りで、config2内の`user.name`が表示されません。

環境は、

- PowerShell 7.3.4
- git version 2.40.1.windows.1

です。

なんとか、ホームディレクトリからの相対パスでファイルを指定する方法はないでしょうか

Comment: 私の環境では再現しませんでした(`user.name=Git Tester` が一覧に出力されています)。[マニュアル](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_includes) の記述からすると環境変数 `HOME` が設定されている必要がありそうです。また、本質からはやや逸れますが、質問文中の `~/temp/.gitconfig` ファイルは今回の結果に関与することは無いと思います(`.gitcocnfig` という名前のファイルを置くのは [ホームディレクトリ](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-gitconfig) であり、また仮にこれをホームディレクトリに置いたとしても [global](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-global) スコープ設定よりコマンド `git config include.path ~/temp/config2` で設定した [local](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-local) スコープのものが優先される)。

Comment: 自分の環境では、HOMEを明示的にXDG_CONFIG_HOMEと同じ~/.configと設定しているので、それが悪さをしているのかもしれません。調べてみます

Answer (score -1):

理由がわかりました、結論からいうと環境変数HOMEをXDG_CONFIG_HOMEと同じ、`~/.config`にしていたため参照先がずれていました。
軽く調べたものをまとめると、以下のようになります。

| 環境変数`HOME` | $HOME | path=~/temp/config2の参照先 | 備考 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| なし | c:/Users/<ユーザ名> (PowerShell側で自動的に設定) | ~/temp/config2 |  |
| c:/Users/<ユーザ名> | c:/Users/<ユーザ名> | ~/temp/config2 |  |
| c:/Users/<ユーザ名>/.config | c:/<ユーザ名>/.config (PowerShell側では、`~/.config` | ~/.config/temp/config2 |  |

PowerShell側での`~`が`C:\Users\<ユーザ名>`のままだったので、そこをホームディレクトリとして読み込むと思っていましたが、環境変数として設定したHOMEのディレクトリを基準のホームディレクトリとして参照したため不整合が生じたようです。

対策は、環境変数を設定せずシステムの設定に従うべきということですね

XDG_BASE_DIRECTORY対応は、VIMなどのアプリごとやり直すことにします

以上

Comment: gitの動作にPowerShellは関係ないと思います。ですので、この判断は何か勘違いを含んでいると思います。例えばcmd.exeからgitを実行したら異なる挙動を示すのでしょうか？ なお大前提として、Windowsにおいて環境変数`HOME`は利用されておらず、既定で設定されていませんが、gitはその環境変数`HOME`を参照しているという点があります。

Comment: そのとおりです。PowerShell上では、~が常にc:/Users/<ユーザー名>を指していたので、Gitの場合もそうだと思い込んでいました。上記の表のとおり、環境変数`HOME`を設定すると、そのディレクトリを基準として読み込むのですね。 PowerShellは環境変数`HOME`をシェル実行時に自動変数として生成するので、明示的に`HOME`を設定しない方が問題が少ないという解釈です

Comment: PowerShellにおける**環境変数**は`env:`プレフィックスを付けます。環境変数`$env:HOME`は存在しないはずです。シェルの**内部変数** `$HOME`は確かに存在しますが、gitを含む外部プロセスには無関係です。

Comment: 今回の質問の場合は、自分で環境変数`HOME`=`C:/Users/atsushifx/.config`と設定しました。結果、`$env:HOME`=`c:/Users/atsushifx/.config`, `$HOME`='c:/Users/atsushifx'と2つの変数が存在している状態になっています。Gitのドキュメントによると、pathの`~`は`$HOME`の値になるのですが、`$env:HOME`があると、その値を使うようです